# Parse JSON into ListView Android

Tags: java, json, listview, parsing, hashmap

I am trying to parse my JSON Array which is similar to the following one

```
[{"meta_value":"Firstname","post_id":"225"},{"meta_value":"Firstname","post_id":"226"},...]
```

To a ListView in Android Studio. I tried to get the value form `meta_value` but I get still get Error that it cannot resolve constructer "Arrayadapter,.."
 I am still a beginner, but learning :)
Thank you in advance!

```
  ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
  try {

  JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
  for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String name = jObject.getString("meta_value");
        arrayList.add(name);
        ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(myAdapter);



      }
}
```

Comment: You can find the right answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342925/parse-jsonarray-in-android-studio
Best regards

Comment: Here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342925/parse-jsonarray-in-android-studio :)